# Formal / academic phrase for there is more to the story

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I want to find a more formal or academic sounding way to express the notion that "there is more to the story." Essentially, this phrase is a bit too casual (not to mention over-used)

Context:

> However, after factoring in the latest earnings reports, it's clear
> that ___________________.

Comment: 'there is more to be revealed.'

Comment: If you weren't already using 'factoring in' you could say *it's clear that other factors are involved* or *it's clear (that) there are many factors at play.* You could say, *the picture is incomplete* or *the picture is far from complete.* I think it would be better, though, to replace 'factoring in' with *taking into account* or just *considering*. Then use my first or second suggestion.

Comment: The shortest phrase I can think of is *more remains*. But, as it is, there is no way of choosing between any number of possible phrases. Also as a note, if you're looking for formal phrasing, write **it is**, ***not*** *it's*.

Comment: Don't you think you'd get more help anywhere like SE Writing?